# Visual c++ import libx264.a error

Tags: c++, visual-c++

The x264 code source has been compiled into  libx264.a by msys,the following step is a new created MFC project has been imported with ole32.dll and libx264.a in visual c++ 2005/.

The Debug aplication runs good.
However,one release jumped a message box showed that "the input program of CreateItemMoniker can not be located on the Dynamic Link Library of crtdll.dll".

Dependency Walker showes that "Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module."

Answer (score 1):

Well, the message is accurate.  CreateItemMoniker is imported from ole32.dll, not from "crtdll.dll".  Which in itself is an odd DLL name, it dates back to the 16-bit version of Visual Studio.

You are linking an invalid import library.  That possibly started with "libx264.a", that's a library that was created by the GCC toolchain.  You have to link to ole32.lib to get a proper reference for CreateItemMoniker.

Comment: The MFC aplication has already linked ole32.lib. What does it mean "You have to link to ole32.lib to get a proper reference for CreateItemMoniker.".

Comment: I am not very sure, but I think  libx264.a brings up the mistake.
I compiled libx264.a by steps"configure->make->make install"
Dose it mean there are any other steps should be done to resolve this problem?